# How to set CloudFront Cookies in Exoplayer Android library for HLS streaming?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Where and how do we set cloudfront cookies for HLS streaming in Exoplayer Android library. Is it with DEFAULT COOKIES MANAGER? What is exact way to set cookies. Till now no exact solutions from any links

Answer (score 1):

Try to do set cookies in DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4870#issuecomment-425795374

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of exoplayer is little different from the above mentioned code.here I have posted a simple code that uses a cloudfront signed HLS m3u8 as media source.

---------- Gradle -----------

```
def exoplayer_version = "2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$exoplayer_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayer_version"
```

----------- XML [define a ui.PlayerView] -----------

```
[....]
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
         android:id="@+id/ep_video_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
[....]
```

------------ Fragment ------------

```kotlin
    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null

[...] 

        val sourceURL= "https://a.cloudfront.net/b.m3u8?Policy=eyJT..._&Signature=eZ6....__&Key-Pair-Id=KRSDW..."
// extract Policy, Signature and KeyPairIds
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(sourceURL)
        val policyString: String? = uri.getQueryParameter("Policy")
        val signatureString: String? = uri.getQueryParameter("Signature")
        val keyPairIdString: String? = uri.getQueryParameter("Key-Pair-Id")

// Create a cookie list to send

        var cookieValue = ""
        cookieValue += "CloudFront-Policy=$policyString;"
        cookieValue += "CloudFront-Signature=$signatureString;"
        cookieValue += "CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=$keyPairIdString;"

// httpDataSourceFactory

        val httpDataSourceFactory: HttpDataSource.Factory =
            DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                .setDefaultRequestProperties(mapOf("Cookie" to cookieValue))
                .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true)

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(requireContext(), 
                                httpDataSourceFactory)

        val hlsMediaSource: HlsMediaSource = 
             HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(sourceURL))

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).build()

        exoPlayer.also { exoPlayer ->
            binding.epVideoView.player = exoPlayer
            exoPlayer?.addMediaSource(hlsMediaSource)
            exoPlayer?.prepare()
            exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        }

[...]
```

Incase if you get any 403 from exoplayer, try changing the **userAgent** in httpDataSourceFactory